# Magento 2.3.2 How to add Multiline component field in admin form using ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, address, magento2.3.2

I want to add a field like **Street address** in my custom module. same as customer Address Add from back-end form. it will look like below image.
[image]

How can I add this kind of field using the UI component?

---

**UPDATE:**

I have used the below code to display a multiline component. But it is not displaying a filed label.

```
<field name="address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="size" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiline</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Street</item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

And also I would like to create a field using a new UI-component form method, the above code is an older method.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Fields & label both are not displaying or just label not displaying?

Comment: Field display but, only label not displaying.

Comment: I found that it is default magento bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7428

Comment: Now need to know how to implement a patch of this issue.

Comment: Let me know still if you'll face any issue.

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thanks. +1 for the help :)

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working. have you checked created git issue? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7428

Comment: Yes. I checked and also try my code and it's working. For few minutes, remove if condition for label and check it.

Comment: I have tried after remove if condition. but not working. try with Magento CE-2.3.2 version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97874/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-chirag-patel).

Comment: Check the chat room please.

Answer (score 2):

About multiline fields data, it's render from `vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/Multiline.php` file.

It seems like there are no label fields added before prepare data. So, you need to override the file or use plugin for that.

For testing, you can write code in core file and add this below code :

> vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/Multiline.php

```
public function prepare() {
    $size = abs((int) $this->getData('config/size'));
    $validation = [$this->getData('config/validation')];
    while ($size--) {
        $identifier = $this->getName() . '_' . $size;
        $arguments = [
            'data' => [
                'name' => $identifier,
                'config' => [
                    'dataScope' => $size,
                    'dataType' => static::DATA_TYPE,
                    'formElement' => static::FORM_ELEMENT,
                    'sortOrder' => $size,
                ],
            ],
        ];

        if (!empty($validation[$size])) {
            $arguments['data']['config']['validation'] = $validation[$size];
        }
        // For display label
        if($this->getData('config/formElement') == 'multiline' && $this->getData('config/label') != ''){
            $arguments['data']['config']['label'] = $this->getData('config/label');
        }
        $component = $this->uiComponentFactory->create($identifier, Field::NAME, $arguments);
        $component->prepare();

        $this->components[$identifier] = $component;
    }
    parent::prepare();
}
```

**Note : I do not recommended to change in core files. Create plugins for that.**